# Problem with painting with TImage. I have drawn on the TImage but it is not being painted

Tags: delphi, components, timage, tcustomcontrol

I have created a sample component below. There are 3 `TPanel`s containing 1 `TImage` each. I want the images to paint themselves as instructed in the code. This does not happen.

If you build this component and drop it on a form, you will see no painting, and when executed the program shows no painting.

I am using Delphi 10.4 on a Windows 11 machine.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I tried using the `Paint` method, but this causes a looping error. I just copied the same details from the created components' painting commands into `Paint`. Not a good result.

```
unit Schedule;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Forms;

type
  TEBSSchedule = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    Panel1, Panel2, Panel3: TPanel;
    Image1, Image2, Image3: TImage;
    ScrollBar1, ScrollBar2: TScrollBar;

    procedure Image3MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image3MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image3MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

    procedure CreatePanels;
    procedure CreateScrollBars;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

Procedure Register;

implementation


constructor TEBSSchedule.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width := 400;
  Height := 300;

  CreatePanels;
  CreateScrollBars;
end;

destructor TEBSSchedule.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(Image1) then Image1.Free;
  if Assigned(Image2) then Image2.Free;
  if Assigned(Image3) then Image3.Free;
  if Assigned(Panel1) then Panel1.Free;
  if Assigned(Panel2) then Panel2.Free;
  if Assigned(Panel3) then Panel3.Free;
  if Assigned(ScrollBar1) then ScrollBar1.Free;
  if Assigned(ScrollBar2) then ScrollBar2.Free;

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.CreatePanels;
var
  T: TRect;
begin
  T.Left := 0;
  T.Top := 0;
  Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel1.Parent := Self;
  Panel1.SetBounds(100,0,Self.Width-100,25);
  Panel1.Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akRight];
  Image1 := TImage.Create(Panel1);
  Image1.Parent := Panel1;
  Image1.Align := alClient;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  T.Right := Panel1.Width;
  T.Bottom := Panel1.Height;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(T);

  Panel2 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel2.Parent := Self;
  Panel2.SetBounds(0,Panel1.Height,100,Self.Height-25);
  Panel2.Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akBottom];
  Image2 := TImage.Create(Panel2);
  Image2.Parent := Panel2;
  Image2.Align := alClient;
  Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
  T.Right := Panel2.Width;
  T.Bottom := Panel2.Height;
  Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(T);

   Panel3 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel3.Parent := Self;
  Panel3.SetBounds(Panel2.Width,Panel1.Height,
  Self.Width-Panel2.Width,Self.Height-Panel1.Height);
  Panel3.Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom];
  Image3 := TImage.Create(Panel3);
  Image3.Parent := Panel3;
  Image3.Align := alClient;
  Image3.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  T.Right := Panel3.Width;
  T.Bottom := Panel3.Height;
  Image3.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(T);
  Image3.OnMouseDown := Image3MouseDown;
  Image3.OnMouseMove := Image3MouseMove;
  Image3.OnMouseUp := Image3MouseUp;
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.CreateScrollBars;
begin
  ScrollBar1 := TScrollBar.Create(Self);
  ScrollBar1.Parent := Self;
  ScrollBar1.Kind := sbHorizontal;
  ScrollBar1.Align := alBottom;

  ScrollBar2 := TScrollBar.Create(Self);
  ScrollBar2.Parent := Self;
  ScrollBar2.Kind := sbVertical;
  ScrollBar2.Align := alRight;
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.Image3MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.Image3MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure TEBSSchedule.Image3MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('EBSH', [TEBSSchedule]);
end;


end.
```

Comment: Btw you should remove all the if Assigned tests, Free is nil safe

Comment: yes I will do that in the actual version. Thanks

Comment: Actually you should not Free these components at all, because they have their Owner property set, which means they are automatically destroyed when their owner gets destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

You are not seeing anything painted because there is nothing available to be painted.

When you access the `TImage.Picture.Bitmap` property for the first time, there is no graphic loaded in the `TImage` yet, so the `Bitmap` property getter creates a **blank `TBitmap` object with dimensions of 0x0**.  This is (somewhat) documented behavior (although the wording is a little misleading<sup>1</sup>):

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap

> Use `Bitmap` to reference the picture object when it contains a bitmap. If `Bitmap` is referenced when the picture contains a Metafile or Icon graphic, the graphic won't be converted ([Types of Graphic Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Types_of_Graphic_Objects)). Instead, the original contents of the picture are discarded **and `Bitmap` returns a new, blank bitmap.**

<sup>1</sup>: What the documentation *really means* is something more like this:

> Use `Bitmap` to reference the picture object when it contains a bitmap. If `Bitmap` is referenced when the picture does not contain a bitmap graphic, any existing graphic won't be converted ([Types of Graphic Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Types_of_Graphic_Objects)). Instead, the original contents of the picture are discarded **and `Bitmap` returns a new, blank bitmap with no size yet.**

You are thus drawing on the `Bitmap.Canvas` outside of the bounds of the `TBitmap`'s available drawing area.

To fix this, you need to resize the `TBitmap` object before you can then draw anything on it, eg:

```
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(Image1.Width, Image1.Height); // <-- ADD THIS!
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
```